# How to modify IIS query string limit programatically with C#?

Tags: c#, iis, web-config

I would like to change the global configuration of IIS so that the query string limit (default 2048) is changed to a higher value (like 4096). I know how to achieve it usin gthe IIS manager but I want to have C# code that will do it. I looked into the structure of the global configuration (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config) and found that I need to create or modify system.webServer/security/requestLimits/requestFiltering and change maxQueryString to 4096. However, every attempt to do this fails.

For all of the below things, appHostConfig is server.GetApplicationHostConfiguration, server is a Servermanager, and server.commitchanges is located directly below.

I first tried

```
ConfigurationSection rFSection = appHostConfig.GetSection("system.webServer/security/requestFiltering");
ConfigurationElementCollection rfCollection = rFSection.GetCollection();
ConfigurationElement rfElement = rfCollection.CreateElement("requestLimits");
rfElement["maxQueryString"] = "4096";
rfCollection.Add(rfElement);
```

but that threw `System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Then I tried

```
ConfigurationSection rFSection = appHostConfig.GetSection("system.webServer/security/requestFiltering");
ConfigurationElement rfElement;
try
{
    rfElement = rFSection.GetChildElement("requestLimits");
} catch
{
    rfElement = rFSection.GetCollection().CreateElement("requestLimits");
}
rfElement["maxQueryString"] = "4096";
rFSection.GetCollection().Add(rfElement);
```

but then that threw `System.InvalidCastException Specified cast is not valid.`

**I am on .NET 4.8**

I am now out of ideas on how to achieve this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't you simply add it to your web.config like its described in the docu? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/

Comment: which `.NET` version are you using?

Comment: I am using .NET 4.8 @iSR5

Comment: @Ralf I want to add it to the global configuration so it filters down to all sites.

Comment: You need to read more about `Microsoft.Web.Administration` API to learn its basic pattern and how to access different settings: 1) `rFSection.GetCollection()` is clearly wrong, as `requestLimits` is a child element, and `requestFiltering` is not a collection. 2) `= "4096"` is also wrong. To assign `int` or `uint`, just pass the number via `= 4096`. BTW, changing IIS settings from within a web app is in general bad and not secure.

Comment: @LexLi I will go read that now. Also, this isn't a web app at all.

Comment: You might find more examples from https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager, which is not only an IIS Manager clone, but also has its own `Microsoft.Web.Administration` implementation to illustrate how the things work internally. If you are calling MWA from a console/desktop/Windows service app, then that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. I was treating it like a collection when it is an element with attributes. This is the code:

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/requestFiltering");
ConfigurationElement rlr = section.GetChildElement("requestLimits");
rlr.SetAttributeValue("MaxQueryString", 4096);
            
serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

The moral of this is: Always familiarize yourself with the configuration schematic before wasting three hours trying to use it